# FileField Upload to not working as expected in Django

Tags: django

I have a Django app, which should upload a file that is entered through a Filefield to be uploaded to a particular path for example I have a folder named "Uploadfiles", so I just want my files entered in the file field to be uploaded in that folder.

I tried, but my file is not getting uploaded to that folder.

so below is my code :

```
class Uploadedfile(models.Model):
    def file_path(self, filename):
        return f'uploaded_files/{self.server}/{self.path.replace(":", "$", 1)}/{filename}'

    files_to_upload = models.FileField(
        upload_to=file_path,
        default=None,
        validators=[validate_file]
    )
    path = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    server = MultiSelectField(choices=server_list)

    salesforceticket = models.ForeignKey(
        Salesforceticket,
        related_name='uploadedfile',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.salesforceticket)
```

Views.py

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
        filled_form = SnippetForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        filled_formset = FilesFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if filled_form.is_valid() and filled_formset.is_valid():
            salesforceticket = filled_form.save(commit=False)
   
            SalesforceNumber = filled_form.cleaned_data['salesforceNumber']
            sourcefile = filled_formset.cleaned_data['files_to_upload']
```

template/file.html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'files' %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{SnippetForm|materializecss}}
  <br>
  <table class="table form-table table-bordered table-sm">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                    
                <div class="large-4 columns">
                                                        <p style="text-align:left">I am a Python developer and I like Django.</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                                            
                                                    {% for form_data in formset %}
                                                            <tr class="item">
                                                                    <td>
                                                                            {{ form_data.files_to_upload|materializecss }}
                                                                    </td>
                                            </html>
```

since am new to Django, I don know whether I made any mistake. Can anyone please help me out with this

Comment: got any errors or traceback?

Comment: no , i am not getting any errors . but it is not working

Comment: show relevant views and template codes.

Comment: added template and views.py @Sumithran

Comment: filled_form and filled_formset should be save [ save() ].

Comment: Is there anyother way without saving the filled_form and filld_formset @SuryaPratapRana